# combine @sql query with temp table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to combine SQL query with temp table data like below.
My sql query is

```
declare @temp table(Id int)
insert into @temp values(10)
insert into @temp values(20)

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)=''
set @SQL='select * from nomination where id in (select id from @temp)'
exec (@sql)
```

when execute above query, it throws error as Must declare the table variable "@temp".
can any help to solve this?

Comment: you can use temprorary table :
create table #temp(id int)
insert into #temp  values(10)
insert into #temp  values(20)

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)=''
set @SQL='select * from nomination where id in (select id from #temp)'
exec (@sql)

Comment: Why are you using "dynamic" SQL at all here; it's not dynamic...